# Babel Parser Error on attempting to build app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, babeljs

I am attempting to deploy my node js app to Heroku but it keeps failing.

I have already set `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`. Build script works fine on my local machine

This is my package.json file

```
"release": "npm run clean && npm run build-app && npm run start",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist && mkdir dist && babel . --out-dir dist",
    "build-app": "babel . -s -d dist --presets=@babel/env --ignore node_modules",
```

Build should be successful but this is the error I get on Heroku

```
> rm -rf ./dist && mkdir dist && babel . --out-dir dist

[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ajv/dist/regenerator.min.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
{ SyntaxError: /tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/index.js: Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode (166:15)
  164 | function chmodShim (to, cb) {
  165 |   var then = times(2, cb, cb)
> 166 |   fs.chmod(to, 0755, then)
      |                ^
  167 |   fs.chmod(to + ".cmd", 0755, then)
  168 | }
  169 | 
    at Parser.raise (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3851:17)
    at Parser.readNumber (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:4702:14)
    at Parser.getTokenFromCode (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:4474:14)
    at Parser.nextToken (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:4049:12)
    at Parser.next (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3989:10)
    at Parser.eat (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3994:12)
    at Parser.expect (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5153:10)
    at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6106:14)
    at Parser.parseSubscript (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6016:29)
    at Parser.parseSubscripts (/tmp/build_3a8af19f4cfbd2b3f05ba2bc3775012d/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5935:19)
  pos: 4390,
  loc: Position { line: 166, column: 15 },
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! banka@1.0.0 build: `rm -rf ./dist && mkdir dist && babel . --out-dir dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the banka@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.zXFlw/_logs/2019-04-19T07_15_46_065Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Comment: This seems like an issue with paths, apparently the relative path for ignoring folders and files doesn't work, does anyone have any clues as to how to bypass this besides the answer given by OP?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the error was due to the `.` flag in my build script telling babel to transpile my node_modules folder, even using the `--ignore node_modules` flag refused to work for me for some yet to be understood reason. I had to restructure my entire folder to move my node_modules folder beyond the scope of my babel script to finally make it function properly

Comment: Got the same problem. I don't think you need to refactor though, just build the entry file and the source folder separately

Comment: @BrianLe How do you do that?