# BABEL_PARSE_ERROR when deploying Nodejs app on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, deployment

I am deploying node js application on heroku server. I am using webpack for es6 syntax and its working fine everything on my local.

But when I am trying to deploy code on heroku it gives BABEL_PARSE_ERROR.

```
remote:        > taleem-backend@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166
remote:        > rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist
remote:        
remote: SyntaxError: /tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/gatsby-browser.js: Unexpected token (7:9)
remote: 
remote:   5 | 
remote:   6 | export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
remote: > 7 |   return <Layout {...props} >{element}</Layout>
remote:     |          ^
remote:   8 | }
remote:   9 | 
remote:     at Parser.raise (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7017:17)
remote:     at Parser.unexpected (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8395:16)
remote:     at Parser.parseExprAtom (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9673:20)
remote:     at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9259:23)
remote:     at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9239:21)
remote:     at Parser.parseExprOps (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9109:23)
remote:     at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9082:23)
remote:     at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9037:21)
remote:     at Parser.parseExpression (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8989:23)
remote:     at Parser.parseReturnStatement (/tmp/build_dbe1f098c9b56734350ccb6e4f4c0166/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11057:28) {
remote:   pos: 209,
remote:   loc: Position { line: 7, column: 9 },
remote:   code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR'
remote: }
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! taleem-backend@1.0.0 build: `rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Above error is coming in node_modules, but I am already ignoring my node_modules in webpack.config.js and I double check its working fine in my local (ignore logic)

```
heroku local web
```

I run above command as its mentioned in heroku docs and 
 its also working fine
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

But when I run

```
git push heroku master
```

I got above error. Kindly help me on this to fix this issue.

Thanks

**EDIT**

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    api.cache(true)
    return {
        ignore: [
            "babel.config.js",
            "dist",
            "package.json",
            "node_modules",
            '.babelrc'
        ]
    }
}
```

package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/bin/www",
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist",
    "watch:dev": "nodemon"
  },
```

Now I fixed that by updating app structure

```
"build": "rimraf dist/ && babel app/ --out-dir dist",
```

Comment: To do so just visit this page > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758607/babel-parser-error-on-attempting-to-build-app-on-heroku

Comment: Thanks Ali, 

The only solution I found is to restructure your app folder then it will work fine. Any better solution is welcome.

Comment: Can you please post your `package.json` + `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: What about Babel.config.js? Trying to find evidence you are using a JSX transpiler.